# Vertex won't work on SFML 2.3

Tags: c++, sfml, vertex

Trying to draw a line just like in the tutorials of SFML using the vertex method. Here is what I copied from the tutorial :

```
sf::Vertex line[] =
{
  sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(10, 10)),
  sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(150, 150))
};
```

in a small main()  but i get : 
[image]

Help ?

Comment: It's a linking issue, did you check that the compile line is right?

Comment: I use a Makefile to compile, here are my flags  :
g++ -Wall -Wextra -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -fPIC

Answer (score 0):

As your source code depends on SFML, you should put your *.o files before sfml libraries in the linking command, like that for example :

```
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```